# Shortcut Virus: All contents of my USB gets transferred into an unnamed hidden folder

Tags: virus

Whenever I connect any USB into my PC. All of the contents of my USB gets thrown into a hidden unnamed folder which is getting irritating.

I have tried to search online for solutions but none of them perfectly matches my case. I tried to follow [this article](http://blog.piratelufi.com/2013/02/usb-flash-drive-contents-replaced-with-a-single-shortcut/)  by using *Unlocker* and *Process Explorer* to identify the process used by the virus, it didn't help me because I didn't have an autorun.inf file that was used to pinpoint the virus.

And yes, I can restore content by going to **command prompt** and typing `D:\> attrib -s -h -a -r /s /d *.*` where D: is my USB.

What I want to do is to kill that virus that is within my PC and stop this from happening before I resort to reformatting my computer.

---

**My USB Contents :**

- desktop.ini
- IndexerVolumeGuid
- prtpvrtpR VTPRRT... (some file that seems to be generated with a random filename)

**desktop.ini**

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=%systemroot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,7
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll
IconIndex=7
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the infection on any other PC?

Comment: @Nikhil_CV Hi, as far as I know the infection is contagious. Although I am not 100% sure of it. Some of my blockmates has this virus, that may also be the source of the infection.

Comment: You do not say what it is you are connecting, a thumb drive, and external hard drive, a camera? If a flash drive, it might also be helpful if you told us the model and make.

Comment: Is the PC a personal PC, a work PC, other? Do you have security software installed that might be quarantining the files?

Comment: Use the tools (namely Malwarebytes antimalware, Eset online Scanner and Emsisoft Emergency Kit) listed at http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/588576/shortcut-virus/page-2 . They are recommended by user 'severac' for removal.

Comment: I know its a shotgun approach, but it should help. :)

Comment: Since you already have process explorer, why not look for handles on your flash drive? It's not a sure shot, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @schroeder Sorry. It's a flashdrive by kingston. Also, I just tried plugging in my external hard drive, it didnt get infected. But any flashdrives or thumbdrives etc. gets infected. And yes, the pc is a personal PC. And I use Avast as my antivirus. EDIT: I just plugged in my camera and the it didn't get infected, same thing with SD cards, micro SD cards and cellphones.

Comment: Apart from all the solutions mentioned, you can also try installing VirusTotal utility, and then check for any suspicious processes that you see.